# if {an} is a negative decreasing sequence, can it be convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to do an exercise where I have to prove that a decreasing and negative sequence is convergent, and I don´t know which are the steps I should follow.

I would be really thankful if you helped me.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try an example?

Comment: A monotone sequence converges iff it is bounded at the direction it is monotone. Thus, a descending sequence, negative or whatever, will be convergent iff it is bounded below.

Comment: The answer on the question on the title is: "yes". E.g. let $a_n=\frac1n-2$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: thank you! you helped me a lot

Comment: Furthermore, a sequence which is decreasing and bounded below is convergent. You can prove from the definition that $L:= \inf \{ a_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ is the limit of the sequence.